# Insert data to one table from list of tables (SELECT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES)

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql, information-schema

need your kind help.

***I need to make following insertions:***

```
`INSERT INTO results_archive(`id_original`,`client_name`,`keywords`,`search_type`) 
SELECT `id`,`client_name`,`keywords`,`search_type` 
FROM {here I need to loop list of tables obtained from ***another SELECT***} 
WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)`
```

and this is ***another SELECT***:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='repute' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'results_%'
```

Thank you for your HELP in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the list of tables be dynamic in a single SQL query. Table names, column names, and other syntax must be fixed at the time the query is prepared.

You must write some other application code to fetch the list of tables, and then construct one or more dynamic SQL queries to use those table names.

You have to do this in two steps like that.

Comment: Could you please show me an example of that two steps? Thank you!

Comment: Come on, you should be able to figure out how to write a loop and format a variable into a string.

Comment: I can SELECT from MySQL, loop it in Python and send it back to MySQL with INSERT, but I want to do it purely in MySQL.
Unfortunately I am not good in SQL, otherwise I was not asking for help. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, use Python. Don't try to do this purely in MySQL. It's more trouble than it's worth. SQL was originally designed to be used _together_ with an application coding language.